# Does this change to the limit of a functional sequence preserve equality?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, uniform-convergence

I am taking an analysis course at university and one of the recent problems we had was about defining $e^x$ by

$$e^x = \lim_{n\to \infty} \Big(1 + \frac{x}{n}\Big)^n$$

Now, I've seen elsewhere that you can define e^x by

$$e^x = \lim_{n\to 0} \Big(1 + nx\Big)^\frac{1}{n}$$

and I can understand how this is derived from the first definition with

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \Big(1 + \frac{x}{n}\Big)^n = \lim_{n\to 0} \Big(1 + \frac{x}{1/n}\Big)^\frac{1}{n} = \lim_{n\to 0} \Big(1 + nx\Big)^\frac{1}{n}$$

but I was wondering if it is true in general that for any uniformly convergent functional sequence $(f_n)$ we can say that $(f_\frac{1}{n})$ is also uniformly convergent with

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n = \lim_{n\to 0}f_\frac{1}{n}$$

After a bit of looking, I haven't been able to find any documentation on this or proof of this proposition, although intuitively it seems correct. Any guidance on where to look or start would be appreciated.

Comment: If $n$ is an integer variable  then the right side does not even make sense. If it is a  real variable the two sides are equal.

Comment: If $\lim\limits_{y \to +\infty}f(x,y)=g(x)$ for real $y$ then, using $z=\frac1y$, you can say $\lim\limits_{z \to 0^+}f(x,\frac1z)=g(x)$ too